# <vector> in C++ weird behavior

Tags: c++, vector

[image: vector in c++ terminated the program]

I'm a complete beginner in c++.
I want to know why my first for loop worked fine and output the last element that I added. But the second for loop was unable to output the last element.

if I had four elements in the vector from the beginning I might not get this error message. But what really happened in the background?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int>vec;
    vec={2,3,4};
    vec[3]=9;
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        cout<<vec[i]<<endl;

    }
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        cout<<vec.at(i)<<endl;
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Holy Hand Grenade: i < vec.size()! i ==3 is deadly: Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Tip: Don't walk off the end of arrays, but also use the [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of old-fashioned indexing like this. `for (auto& v : vec)` is all you need.

Comment: Tip: Declare in one shot like `std::vector<int> vec = { 2, 3, 4 }` and then `vec.push_back(9)` to append.

Comment: With vector initialization vec = {2,3,4} the vector vec size is 3. And with indices starting from 0, vec[3] = 9 will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: `vec.at()` checks boundaries and throws an exception, visible at the end of output, `vec[i]` does not.